# Click on grid in windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I Have grid in my `XAML` and couple of buttons on it.
And i want to get notified every time the user press the grid so i add `MouseEnter` Event:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF1F1F1F" MouseEnter="TapMouse">
```

But my problem is that every time one of the buttons is pressed so this method called too.

Any way to disable it? or any other way to implement it?

Thanks

Comment: How are you using your buttons? In code-behind too?

Comment: I just add the buttons on another grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set break points in each event block.

Find out which one is firing first the `button` or the `grid`

Declare a bool at the top and call it `buttonClicked = false;`

if it is the `button` then put a `buttonClicked = true` in the but event

if its the `grid` then I would try and see if you could use a `buttonOver` event

In the grid event wrap it all in an if statement `if(!buttonClicked)`

That should work

**NOTE** you will have to also add a `buttonClicked = false` into maybe focus lost event for the button

**Update:**
Coming back to this answer years later I acknowledge it's ghettoness. Though i'd like to update it, I think leaving it as a time capsule of my own ignorance is much more beneficial.